# using apache as proxy to modify request content

Tags: php, apache, sockets, proxy

I am planing for a project to create a custom proxy that intercept request and modify it's content before forwarding it to the targeted server. The purpose for that is to replace somes tags inside the HTTP request body by some values only known by the proxy server.

I managed to make a little proof of concept using php and socket in a daemon mode that work quite well, but I wonder if there is a solution to avoid the full php daemon using apache as a proxy that pass the requests to a php script allowing to modify it before forwarding it to the targeted server.

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a way to handle this.
I have defined a default vhost on my apache and added the following rewrite rules on the .htaccess of the default vhost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

all requests are passed to the index.php and then it is possible to manipulate the request and forward it to the good url.

```
curl -x localhost:80 http://www.google.com
```

will be intercepted by the index.php of the default vhost.